# C# MySqlConnection crash application on incorrect Certificate info

Tags: c#, mysql

If The `CertificatePassword` or `CertificateFile` of the MySQL connection is incorrect it crashes my application.  The reason this is an issue is that the user is the one that enters in the connection information.  This means that if they mistype `CertificatePassword` or `CertificateFile` the application crashes instead of telling them the error message.  I figured putting a `try` around the code would work, it did not.

```
try
{
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conString);
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlCMD, con);
        RSACryptoServiceProvider.UseMachineKeyStore = true;
        var provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        con.Open();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        da.Fill(dt);
        cmd.Dispose();
        con.Close();
}
catch (MySqlException x)
{
        //Error logic
}
```

The application crashes on `con.Open();` with the error;

> An unhandled exception of type
>
> 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' occurred in
>   MySql.Data.dll Additional information: The system cannot find the file
>   specified.

Please note: If the `CertificatePassword` or `CertificateFile` is correct this code works perfectly.  Also if the user enters in anything wrong other than `CertificatePassword` or `CertificateFile` then the application returns an error message to the user.

I just want to give the user a chance to fix their error instead of having to restart the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your code is only catching an exception if it is of type [`MySqlException`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqlexception.html). Anything else will just get passed back up the call stack, or as you are finding out, will cause your application to terminate. You could try catching that specific exception, which in this case is a [`CryptographicException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptographicexception(v=vs.110).aspx) by adding another catch block:

```
try
{
    //snip
}
catch (MySqlException x)
{
    //Error logic
}
catch(CryptographicException cex)
{
    //logic to handle crypto exception
}
```

Or you can change your exception handler to catch everything:

```
try
{
    //snip
}
catch (Exception x)
{
    //Error logic for all exceptions
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `using` to handle the connection and add a `catch` exception as well

```
try
{
    using MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conString)
    {
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    using MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlCMD, con)
    {
    RSACryptoServiceProvider.UseMachineKeyStore = true;
    var provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
    con.Open();
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    da.Fill(dt);
    }
}
}
catch (MySqlException x)
{
    //Error logic
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```